# Creating a module in Browserify/6to5ify which can be consumed by SystemJS

Tags: javascript, browserify, ecmascript-6, babeljs, systemjs

I have four ES6 modules and one module that exposes data from the other four modules like this:

```
export { Board } from './board';
export { Card } from './card';
export { Game } from './game';
export { Player } from './player';
```

My goal is to have a single JavaScript module file that I can consume via the systemjs api:

```
import { Card } from 'game';
```

It seems the best way to recursively compute and concatenate dependencies is through browserify, and the best way to compile to ES5 from ES6 is 6to5. So, I looked to the 6to5ify node module. I copied and pasted the code from the [example](https://github.com/6to5/6to5ify):

```
var fs = require("fs"),
    browserify = require("browserify"),
    to5ify = require("6to5ify");

browserify({ debug: false })
  .transform(to5ify)
  .require("./src/main.js", { entry: true })
  .bundle()
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./dist/game.js"));
```

Finally, I load game.js into another ES6 web project. However, At this point I get errors, and the systemjs module loader starts looking for the dependencies of the game.js module as if they were local dependencies:

> GET http://localhost:9000/client/board.js 404 (Not Found)
>   es6-module-loader.src.js:2510
>
> GET http://localhost:9000/client/card.js 404 (Not Found)
>   es6-module-loader.src.js:2510
>
> GET http://localhost:9000/client/game.js 404 (Not Found)
>   es6-module-loader.src.js:2510
>
> GET http://localhost:9000/client/player.js 404 (Not Found)
>   es6-module-loader.src.js:2510

However, the output of my build file includes the modules above, and it can be found [here](https://github.com/davismj/kyu-core/blob/master/dist/kyu-core.js).

Since the problem could be with browserify, with 6to5, with the way systemjs loads modules, or the way it parses and reads the contents of the built file, I'm not sure where to look or who to ask.

Comment: Your example build link no longer works, FYI. How are you setting up SystemJS?

Comment: fixed, and through jspm, i'm using the default config on this repo: https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation

Comment: browserify bundle looks good to me. It might not play well with systemjs but loaded in browser on its own it should work fine.